# Creating multiple, independent Gaussian plume outlines in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, gaussian-plume

In an effort to create buffers that preferentially capture downwind populations of numerous air pollutant sources, I would like to create Gaussian-like plumes in arcgis (or in another program such as ALOHA that can easily be imported into arcgis). I have several US states broken up into 36x36 km grids, each with an assigned mean wind speed, direction, and other meteorology, and population counts. I would like to capture the downwind populations that would be exposed to emissions from each grid. "Downwind" can be defined in many ways, and one approach would be to create a Gaussian (or Gaussian-like) plume for each cell and then use a portion of them as buffer outlines.

However, I have not come across any clear method of creating buffers that can be weighted toward downwind areas, or a method of creating Gaussian plumes within ArcGIS. Any ideas?

Also, I posed a similar question here:  [Creating vectors based on U and V values using ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222349/creating-vectors-based-on-u-and-v-values/222364?noredirect=1#comment344028_222364)

The suggested solution is different from what I am asking currently, but the background information may be helpful.

Comment: doesnt ALOHA do that? you can export models to arcgis with the extension toolbar...

Comment: The problem that I encountered with ALOHA and other similar programs is that they are not set up to generate numerous plumes. I would need to generate thousands of plumes.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @whuber](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223241/creating-multiple-independent-gaussian-plume-outlines-in-arcgis/248242#comment349490_223241):

> It all depends on what exactly you mean by a "Gaussian plume."  Unless
>   all their parameters are the same, your calculation cannot be
>   performed though any efficient combination of standard "raster
>   algebra" calculations.  (I had to do exactly this operation almost 20
>   years ago and ended up writing custom code for it.  See
>   http://www.directionsmag.com/authors/bill-huber/121719 and follow
>   links to the "convolution" articles.)